# Custom registration User validation

Tags: plugin-development, users, registration

I'm building a custom registration process in which a set of entries **and** a user are created at the same time.

**Currently I'm not able to pass back my errors in my controller into the front-end template.**

(The following code ***should*** error out on purpose to test this functionality)

**In my plugin controller:**

```
$user = new UserModel;
$wasSaved = craft()->users->saveUser($user);

if ($wasSaved) {
     $was_assigned = craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, array(1));
} else {
     $user->addErrors($user->getErrors());
     var_export($user->getErrors());
     return false;
}
```

**In my template**

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
{% if errors %}
  <ul class="errors">
     {% for error in errors %}
         <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% if account.getErrors is defined %}
    {{ _self.errorList(account.getErrors()) }}
{% endif %}
```

With the `var_export($user->getErrors());` in my controller, I can see the errors at the top of the page:

```
array ( 'username' => array ( 0 => 'Username cannot be blank.', 1 => 'Username cannot be blank.', ),
'email' => array ( 0 => 'Email cannot be blank.', 1 => 'Email cannot be blank.', ), )
```

but these errors are not making it back into the actual template.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not returning the user model back to the template.

You need something like this in your controller.

```
craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
    'account' => $user
));
```